# Bash - How to put an array inside values of variable?

Tags: shell, variable, array

I have a web.txt file which contains:

```
youtube
facebook
google
```

My sh file contains:

```
readarray web < web.txt
url = www.website.com
```

Commands I have used:

```
readarray web < web.txt
url = www."$web".com

ping url
```

Expected output:

```
ping youtube.com
ping facebook.com
ping google.com
```

What should be the right syntax? Thanks!

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with arrays ..... the problem is with `bash parameter substitution`

Answer (score 5):

If you *really* want to print the expected output shown, then

```
$ readarray -t web < web.txt
$ printf 'ping www.%s.com\n' "${web[@]}"
ping www.youtube.com
ping www.facebook.com
ping www.google.com
```

However if you want to actually ping the hosts, the probably `xargs` is simpler e.g.

```
xargs -a web.txt -I{} ping -c1 "www.{}.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prepend `www.` and append `.com` to the strings read from the file `web.txt` and use `ping` on the resulting strings:

```
while IFS= read -r company; do
    ping "www.$company.com"
done <web.txt
```